# Does it make a difference using self for a temporary variable in a Python method?

Tags: python, class

I sometimes need to use temporary variables in method definitions that aren't used outside the method. Is there any difference in behaviour between using `self.MyVariable` and `MyVariable` in the class definitions below? Which is the better approach and why?

Example 1: `self.MyVariable`

```
class MyClass:
    def Hello(self, Name):
        self.MyVariable = "Hello " + Name
        return self.MyVariable
```

Example 2: `MyVariable`

```
class MyClass:
    def Hello(self, Name):
        MyVariable = "Hello " + Name
        return MyVariable
```

Comment: If you use `self`, I don't think it will be temporary anymore, and you probably won't need to return such value from the method.

Comment: As a style note, you generally don't capitalize methods or variables in Python, and underscore separation is preferred over camel case. `def hello(self, name):` and `my_variable = ` would be more in keeping with usual Python style.

Comment: OK thanks @Peter - I see now that the naming convention you describe is specified in PEP8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first creates a lasting reference on the class instance, and will be available on the object outside the scope of your method. The latter creates a purely local reference, which will not be available outside the method. Which is better depends on the situation, but if it's actually intended to only be a temporary variable use a local (non-`self`) variable.

Case 1:

```
>>> foo = MyClass()
>>> foo.MyVariable
...
AttributeError: 'MyClass' object has no attribute 'MyVariable'
>>> foo.Hello('bar')
'Hello bar'
>>> foo.MyVariable
'Hello bar'
```

Case 2 is as above, except that `MyVariable` is still not an attribute of the object after calling `Hello`.

Answer (score 5):

The first usage would surprise me if I were looking at your code since it would make me think the variable was being used somewhere else in the class.

Since the first is surprising and makes your intent harder to discern, I'd say the latter is more pythonic, and better in any language that works more or less the same way.

Answer (score 3):

I would do neither, I would just return `"Hello " + Name`, you are not using `MyVariable` anywhere so there is no need to create it and definitely no need to make it an attribute:

```
class MyClass:
    def hello(self, name):
        return  "Hello " + name
```

Comment: A good point, I answered assuming that the OP has an actual reason to use variables that's more complex than the example.

Comment: In the actual code I need to fill a list with values from a generator and then return the list. I don't know how I could do this without a temporary variable to append the values to as they are generated.

Comment: @jweob, just return a list comprehension

Comment: Or, for that matter, `return list(some_generator)`.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper, yes, I  was going to suggest that but maybe there is some logic that decides what to keep, if not then yes simply calling list will work.

Comment: Right. For the OP: `return list(...)` will construct and return a new list containing all elements generated by the generator. `return [x for x in some_generator if x > 5]` will construct and return a new list containing some of the elements of the generator - you can use any expression you like as long as it evaluates to something that can be evaluated as a boolean. `return [x for x in some_generator]` is equivalent to `return list(some_generator)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use example 2. Using `self.` is only necessary if you would like to use your variable in another method of this class or would like to access it later on the instance.